# How to append view to an element

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

What statement do I use to append my template in the div "#draggableContainers"? I am missing something very simple.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Untitled Page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script src="handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>

<script id="draggableTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<p>{{value}}</p>
</script>

<script src="practice.js"></script>
```

and the js file:

```
var DraggableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {

        var source = $("#draggableTemplate").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var attr = {
            value: "Punit"
        };
        var html = template(attr);
        (this.$el).append(html);
    },
    events: {
        "mouseenter .items": "changeColor",
        "mouseleave .items": "changeColor2"
    },
    changeColor: function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#BCB29A");
    },
    changeColor2: function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFF9A");
    }
});

var draggable_view = new DraggableView();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to compile template. If yes, below are code

```
  var draggableSource   = $("#draggableTemplate").html();
  var draggableTemplate = Handlebars.compile(draggableSource);
  var draggable    = cPlanTemplate(yourJsonObJ);  
  $('#draggableContainer').html(draggable);

 <div id="draggableContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thnx for the help. I am able to get the compiled template with associated value. Its just that i am not able to render or append the view to the # draggableContainers div

Answer (score 0):

Guess. You seem to be missing to configure/set `el` of your `DraggableView`. Inside your `render` method you do `(this.$el).append(html);` so what would be `$el` pointing to? If you have not set it it will default to `div` and just create a new `div` element but will never be added to `DOM`.

Have a look at [view.el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)

If you want to set template to `#draggableContainers`, try setting `el` as below:

```
var DraggableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#draggableContainers',
    initialize : function() {
       this.render();
    },
```

Make sure you have `#draggableContainers` existing in your DOM.

Comment: I am unable to append the template with value to the div #draggableContainers. :-(